# Angular Elements WebComponents external DOM Changes

Tags: javascript, angular, element, web-component

**TL;DR**: Deleting the DOM Element of a custom Element created with Angular Elements will lead to sub-routers not loading components

First, the code is [available at Github](https://github.com/ManuelBk/web-component-router-bug).

Sadly, I did not get a stackblitz version running, but locally, after a clone, npm install and ng serve it should run fine.

**About the general structure:**

The Project shows an example of a WebComponent exposed by an Angular App via Elements.
The WebComponent is used in the index.html, which is referred as container Application. 
The use case here is a little bit constructed, but the navigation that occurs, when clicking
on the two top bottoms is comparable to the real world use case.

*Normally this WebComponent would have been used in an AngularJS legacy Application. Since there are many overlappings between the two root views (overview1 overview2) it is used in two AngularJS components, in between ui-router handled navigation. This means, that exactly this constructed actions happen. The DOM Elements will be deleted and re-added.*

**So basically the problem is:**

If I am deleting DOM Elements of a WebComponent (so deleting the CustomElement itself) from external, and then re-adding it with another route, The Child-route components of this will not get loaded. If there is a short delay (50ms), everything works fine.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Load page and click an the "switch with delay" button.
2. Reveal Detail Component
3. Switch to the other Overview by clicking "switch with delay" again.
4. Reveal Detail Component

=> Everything should work fine

Repeat the same steps, but this time click only on "switch directly".

**Prior Investigations**

What I already debugged is the Router. So I went through the log messages with "enable tracing"
and they seemed to be no differences. Afterwards I compared the Components' Lifecycle and 
the thing I noticed is, that in the working example the old `Detail**1**Component` Object will get destroyed a new `Detail**1**Component` one will be created and directly destroyed afterwards and then everything regarding the `Detail**2**Component` will get constructed.

On the not working example it is like this:
A new `Detail**1**Component` will get constructed again and destroyed afterwards. Then the old `Detail**1**Component` will get destroyed. Then nothing regard the `Detail**2**Component` will get constructed.

So routing seems to work fine, but components won't get loaded in this case, maybe due to a strange lifecycle, because of the Detachment of the View to the ViewModel happening due to hard deleting those WebComponent in DOM.

Maybe I am just dumb and did something fundamentally wrong, but I could not find anything in the Web regarding this problem and every solution I tried by myself just resulted in a workaround like establishing a delay.

Comment: I only can assume: `setTimeout` triggers the change-detection from Angular (via the help of `zonejs`). When we manipulate the DOM directly and not in an Angular way, it is not able to recognize the change. So wrapping in a `setTimeout()` without a delay would work possibly too.

Comment: Thank you for your input, with a Timeout value of 0 the example will not work, I need to set it atleast to ~5-10ms.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a workaround [available on Github](https://github.com/ManuelBk/web-component-router-bug).
I forced the recreation of the DOM object by attaching a boolean
to the navigation button, which will determine if the DetailComponent
should actually get shown.

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="shown">
```

Then the Outlet will get reevaluated and the DOM will get refilled on clicking the button.
This will effectively mitgating the issues described. 
In my opinion its not the cleanest solution, but cleaner than a timeout, that
even needs to get applied from the outside.
I hope this was helpful and maybe someone might point me to the actual fix and
not only workaround.

Since this was my first question do not hesitate to give me feedback on formal
appearance.